# Android:Disable popup window when entering kiosk mode

Tags: android, kiosk-mode

I have an Android application which uses Kioskmode. When the app start the screen below appears. My question is : Can I disable displaying the screen below that the screen is pinned ? I do not want to display the overlay when entering kiosk mode.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Yea that's possible. You'll need to make your App a device owner for this purpose.

1. Set up Admin Receiver in manifest
2. Run: adb shell dpm set-device-owner com.package.name/.AdminReceiver

Look here:

- http://wenchaojiang.github.io/blog/realise-Android-kiosk-mode/ - really helpful
- https://sureshjoshi.com/mobile/android-kiosk-mode-without-root/
- https://developer.android.com/work/dpc/dedicated-devices/cookbook#java - if you want to make you kiosk mode app more secure